# Better chat room post tools

Tags: feature-request, usability, chat

I think the tooltips for chat room posts can be improved

[image: chat room post tooltips]

- The onhover gray square is kindof distracting as you move your mouse around
- The arrow is too tiny to click
- Once I manage to open the tooltip, the star and flag are too tiny to click
- If a new post appears while I have a tooltip open, my tooltip moves right before I want to click on something.

Can this be improved?

Comment: I wonder if this is now fixed by the hover area; any thoughts?

Comment: i like it. i still would be interested to see what the google reader style implementation would look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Now a feature request! See [Chat user interface suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57343/chat-user-interface-suggestion)

Cross-posting my answer from [Gravatar bugs and improvements in Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57155/gravatar-bugs-and-improvements-in-chat)

---

I'm not quite sure why, but I think the chat controls would feel more natural on the right, rather than the left.

My idea, as seen below, would be to move the arrow thing to the right side of each chat "bubble". The controls would appear on mouseover, like now, but we could star or flag right from there (the most common tools) without having to have a second window to do that in. The arrow would let you open the window to access other controls, permalink, etc.

On your own posts, which you can't flag or star, you could change the controls to edit/delete, as those are the most common things to do on your own posts.

[image: chat mockup]

If you don't do this, at least close the pop-up window when I click in the text entry field, rather than make me aim for the little gray close button.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make the entire post clickable, and under the post will appear a row of tools, perhaps similar to how google reader works?

[image: google reader?]